# Android Intent Button To Market

Tags: android

I am trying to get a button on my app go to the market place when clicked. Not to another app, but to my publisher area with all my apps. Can anyone help, it just seems to force close at the moment?

`final String APP_MARKET_URL = "market://developer?pub=PUB+ID+HERE";`

Comment: paste the trace. We dont know why it closes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the correct string is `market://search?q=pub:PUB+ID+HERE`

If your string is correct too, try doing it with this code

```
Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(APP_MARKET_URL));
                  market.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                  startActivity(market);
```